# Height not 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, swiper.js

I'm working with Swiper to create vertical slides with thumbnails. The thumbnails works great, but the slider has a strange height even though I have not specified a height. I've tried setting to 100% but that doesn't work. Ideas?

See CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYLxvo

```js
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  autoHeight: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  spaceBetween: 10,
  onSlideChangeEnd: function(swiper) {
    var activeIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
    $(galleryThumbs.slides).removeClass('is-selected');
    $(galleryThumbs.slides).eq(activeIndex).addClass('is-selected');
    galleryThumbs.slideTo(activeIndex, 255, false);
  }
});

var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  freeMode: true,
  centeredSlides: false,
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  direction: 'vertical',
  touchRatio: 0.2,
  onClick: function(swiper, event) {
    var clicked = swiper.clickedIndex
    swiper.activeIndex = clicked; //don't need this
    swiper.updateClasses() //don't need this
    $(swiper.slides).removeClass('is-selected');
    $(swiper.clickedSlide).addClass('is-selected');
    galleryTop.slideTo(clicked, 255, false);
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
}

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

swiper {
  width: 600px;
  display: block !important;
  background: red !important;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery-top .swiper-slide {
  display: inline-block;
}

.gallery-top {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  float: right;
  background: blue;
}

.gallery-thumbs {
  position: relative;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: green;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-size: cover !important;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-active {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide.is-selected {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.2.6/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<swiper class="group">
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing-treatment.jpg?v=1508592020" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing.jpg?v=1508592020" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing-treatment-box.jpg?v=1508594651" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing-treatment.jpg?v=1508592020" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing.jpg?v=1508592020" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0978/6390/products/balancing-treatment-box.jpg?v=1508594651" />
      </div>
    </div>
</swiper>
```

Comment: A Codepen is useful, but please include all relevant code in the question in case their site goes down - then your question would be unanswerable.

Comment: Ops! Sorry! Didn't know how to do it :)

Comment: No problem, I edited your question to include an executable snippet

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after. Can you mock up a quickie image showing what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: @TarynEast As you see the image is smaller than the .swiper-wrapper. So why is the .swiper-wrapper longer than the .swiper-slide? I want it not to be any blue area below the image. However the autoHeight is set to true and .slider-wrapper should adopt its height to the height of the currently active slide, but it is not..

Comment: there is `height: 1440px; margin-bottom: 10px;` set on the `swiper-slide` inside the `swiper-wrapper` div that is causing the issue , track it if it is due to your thumbnail code or swiper js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh the good old 100% height issue...

Try adding the 100% height property to your `HTML` and `BODY`.

```
html,
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The biggest challenges I have always had have been around this, but think of the DOM tree structure that leads up to your slider and ensure that they all expand to 100%.

See how you go with that.